# Loop turns to infinity and makes excel crash

Tags: excel, vba, crash

I'm currently working on a part of my VBA code which is supposed to calculate a total from different tables in another table if some conditions are respected. When my conditions are not respected, the code is fine but when I get into the condition the line with *** makes my code runs to infinity and makes excel crash. I have checked the syntax and it shouldn't be the issue. I honeslty don't understand what is wrong with this Line of code.

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
'----------------------------------------------------
'-- Buildings' peak cooling load total calculation --
'----------------------------------------------------

Dim m As Integer, n As Integer

If Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_YN") = "Yes" Then

If (Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_OF") = "No" Or Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_OF") = "") And (Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_DF") = "No" Or Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_DF") = "") Then

    For m = 1 To Sheet4.Range("NP_NBR_Y")

        For n = 1 To Sheet4.Range("NP_NBR_BUILDING")

            If Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_YN" & n) = "Yes" Then

                ***Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_TABLE")(m + 1, 2).Value = Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_TABLE")(m + 1, 2).Value + Range("INPUTS_BUILDING" & n)(m + 3, 2).Value***

            End If

        Next n

    Next m

End If

If Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_OF") = "Yes" And (Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_DF") = "No" Or Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_DF") = "") Then

    For m = 1 To Sheet4.Range("NP_NBR_Y")

        For n = 1 To Sheet4.Range("NP_NBR_BUILDING")

            If Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_YN" & n) = "Yes" Then

                Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_TABLE")(m + 1, 2).Value = Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_TABLE")(m + 1, 2).Value + Range("INPUTS_BUILDING" & n)(m + 3, 2).Value * Range("INPUTS_BUILDING" & n)(m + 3, 4).Value

            End If

        Next n

    Next m

End If

If (Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_OF") = "No" Or Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_OF") = "") And Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_DF") = "Yes" Then

    For m = 1 To Sheet4.Range("NP_NBR_Y")

        For n = 1 To Sheet4.Range("NP_NBR_BUILDING")

            If Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_YN" & n) = "Yes" Then

                Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_TABLE")(m + 1, 2).Value = Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_TABLE")(m + 1, 2).Value + Range("INPUTS_BUILDING" & n)(m + 3, 2).Value * Range("INPUTS_BUILDING" & n)(m + 3, 5).Value

            End If

        Next n

    Next m

End If

If Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_OF") = "Yes" And Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_DF") = "Yes" Then

    For m = 1 To Sheet4.Range("NP_NBR_Y")

        For n = 1 To Sheet4.Range("NP_NBR_BUILDING")

            If Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_YN" & n) = "Yes" Then

                Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_TABLE")(m + 1, 2).Value = Range("NP_BUILDING_TOTAL_TABLE")(m + 1, 2).Value + Range("INPUTS_BUILDING" & n)(m + 3, 2).Value * Range("INPUTS_BUILDING" & n)(m + 3, 4).Value * Range("INPUTS_BUILDING" & n)(m + 3, 5).Value

            End If

        Next n

    Next m

End If

End If
```

Comment: How is the code being called?

Comment: What is Range("NP_NBR_Y") and what is Sheet4.Range("NP_NBR_BUILDING")?

Comment: @Tim Williams, I don't understand your question

Comment: @Jeeped, Range("NP_NBR_Y") and Sheet4.Range("NP_NBR_BUILDING") are cells in another sheet, cells which contain values (between 1 and 15)

Comment: Too much repetition (Don't Repeat Yourself). Your loop `For m = .... Next m` should only be coded once. You should create a check Boolean (e.g. `canRunLoops` which you calculate up front with those convoluted checks you currently have - you can then have a single `If canRunLoops then : For m = .... Next m : End If`. The important question, how do you know it runs to infinity?

Comment: Off the top of my head (not an answer, but a guess) you should check that your named ranges are defined correctly and giving the right results. Check this in the code itself by debugging and stepping through (F8).

Comment: @AJD, Yeah I agree, my code is a bit repetitive, I didn't know this {canRunLoops}, I'm just starting VBA, thank you for the info.

Comment: @AJD, I know it runs to infinity cause when i'm looking at my excel file while the code is running and the total calculated increases to 45 times the expected result then i get the vba error msgbox and when i press "End" or "Debug", excel crash

Comment: @AJD, i already done that, and the named ranges return the right values, it's by stepping through the code I knew that is this line which is the problem

Comment: Do you, by any chance, call this code in a Worksheet.Change-Event?

Comment: @FunThomas, Yes, the first line of this sheet code is "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)"

Comment: ...that was my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing in the Change-Event - which triggers the call of the Change-Event, where you are changing data - which triggers the call of the Change-Event (and so on...)

To prevent that the event routine are triggered recursively, put this line at the top of the routine:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

and at the end

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! it works perfectly!! you have just ended a 4 hours headaches